# How synchronize multiple machines to insert one single row?

Tags: oracle, synchronization

I have some code that is running on several machines, and accesses an Oracle database. I use this database (among other things) as a synchronization object between the different machines by locking rows.

The problem I have is that when my process is starting, there is nothing yet in the database to rely on for synchronization, and my processes get oracle exceptions about `unique constraint violated` since they all try to insert at the same time.

My solution for now is to catch that precise exception and ignore it, but I don't really like having exceptions being thrown in the normal workflow of my application.

Is there a better way to "test and insert" atomically in a database ? Locking the whole table/partition when inserting a row is not an acceptable solution.

I checked `merge into`, thinking it was my solution, but it produces the same problem.

Comment: you may lock another table(specialy created) for inserts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to use DBMS_LOCK, which allows for user application code to implement the same locking model as the Oracle database does in locking rows and other resources.  You can create an enqueue of type 'UL' (user lock), and define a resource name, and then have multiple sessions lock to their hearts content, without any dependence on data in a table somewhere.  It supports both exclusive and shared locking, so, you have have some processes that can run concurrently (if they take a shared lock) or other processes that run exclusively (if they take an exclusive lock) and they will automatically queue behind the shared lock (if any) that are being held by the other type of process, etc.

It's a a very flexible locking model, and you don't need to rely on any data in any table to implement it.

See the Oracle PL/SQL Packages and Types Reference, for the full scoop on the [DBMS_LOCK package](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lock.htm).

Hope that helps.

Comment: There's no equivalent for `INSERT` unfortunately.

Comment: Hmm...sorry, I didn't read the requirement closely enough.  In this case, you probably want to implement user locks, with DBMS_LOCK and the 'UL' enqueue type.  I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You won't get an error immediately if your PK is policed by a non-unique index, consider:

```
<<SESSION 1>>
SQL> create table afac (
  2     id number,
  3     constraint afac_pk primary key (id) 
  4        deferrable /* will cause the PK to be policed by a non-unique index */
  5  );

Table created.

SQL> insert into afac values (1);

1 row created.

<<SESSION 2>>    
SQL> insert into afac values (1); /* Will cause session 2 to be blocked */
```

Session 2 will be blocked until session 1 either commits or rollbacks. I don't know if this mechanism is compatible with your requirement though.

Comment: hmm, actually this doesn't seem to do the job : I'll still get the same error, only later.

Comment: Well, the first session could delete the offending row before commiting.